# Importing a table from an ASCII file

Tags: matlab, import, ascii, tabular, file-read

I am unable to load a text file in MATLAB. The code I'm using is:

```
y=load('AllReadings.txt')
```

Which produces the error:
[image]

The text file contents are:

```
Heart Rate (BPM)    GSR     Respiration Rate    Ambient Temperature
inf         495     49.96           3

inf         495     49.96           3

inf         495     23.03           7

inf         496     23.03           7

inf         495     23.03           7

inf         496     23.03           11

7.68            496     23.03           11

7.68            496     23.03           14

7.68            496     23.03           14

7.68            496     23.03           15

7.68            496     23.03           14
```

> (Editor's note: the source data is delimited using a combination of tabs and spaces, which is not visible in the rendered output, but can be seen when editing the question.)

Comment: We need to see the `AllReadings.txt` file...

Comment: Please don't paste links to images of your **error messages**. It would be much better to copy/paste your  *error messages* into your question.

Comment: @cbdev420 can you please tell how to upload a file here so that you will be able to see AllReadings.txt file

Comment: @help-info.de the problem is summarized above clearly. I guess no queries are left behind.

Comment: I don't think you can, but since it's a `.txt` file you can copy the contents and add to your question as simple text (wrap it in a code block, to make it better for us to read). If the file is too big with too many lines copy only the first ones and see if that's enough. But you can also go to [Code Sandbox](http://codesandbox.io), add your file there and place the link here on your question.

Comment: @cbdev420 UPDATED. now if yo can help meee

Comment: does your file have empty lines between every line? They should be all together. It seems they're separated and when it goes to line 2 it might be encountering a blank line than it crashed, because every line should have the same number of columns.

Comment: @cbdev420 yes, empty lines are between every line. How to encounter this problem? so that data comes all together in a parallel way?

Comment: First try to create a sample file with maybe 5 lines without any empty lines between them. try to load that and see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it on R2019a, and such a text file can be imported correctly using [`importdata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html):

```matlab
>> y = importdata('AllReadings.txt')
y = 
  struct with fields:

        data: [11×4 double]
    textdata: {'Heart Rate (BPM)    GSR     Respiration Rate    Ambient Temperature'}

>> y.data
ans =
       Inf  495.0000   49.9600    3.0000
       Inf  495.0000   49.9600    3.0000
       Inf  495.0000   23.0300    7.0000
       Inf  496.0000   23.0300    7.0000
       Inf  495.0000   23.0300    7.0000
       Inf  496.0000   23.0300   11.0000
    7.6800  496.0000   23.0300   11.0000
    7.6800  496.0000   23.0300   14.0000
    7.6800  496.0000   23.0300   14.0000
    7.6800  496.0000   23.0300   15.0000
    7.6800  496.0000   23.0300   14.0000
```

Comment: HI! @Dev-iL I tried and its working but can you please guide me how to plot these 4 columns as command ```plot``` is giving error.

Comment: @Sannay If this answer solved your question [please accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234). What you're describing now is a different problem. I have no way of knowing what you're doing wrong, since you didn't post any plotting code, nor did you specify the error. See the documentation of [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#bt2458m) which is **very** clear. Your issue is probably related to trying to plot `Inf` - you should try replacing those with valid values, or at the very least - with `NaN`.

Comment: A much better approach is to use [readtable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html)

Comment: @PhilGoddard please define "better" and provide some foundation for your claim. In this case, _my_ definition was the least amount of configuration and tweaking required from the user - and the result appears to be exactly what the OP needed. Regardless, I think that `importdata` is generally a good function to know, since it can handle various types of inputs, and not just tables.

Comment: Using 'readtable' allows for many more options like automatic date conversion to datetime, and specifying column formats.  Also `table` objects have multiple advantages for tabular data such as being read in here. Some of them are: they can be indexed using traditional row and column, linear, and logical indexing, but also by using the column names (and row names if defined); when tables are displayed the column names appear with the data, rather than in a separate field of a structure, which makes for easier identification; and they can be saved very easily (using `writetable`.)

Answer (score 0):

in response to [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56564885/read-a-text-file-in-matlab-with-a-header-and-all-the-data?noredirect=1#comment99709953_56564885)

Here's a dummy file, since the OP doesn't have any data:

```
header1|header2|header3|header4
adfads|sjk|jkghj|jdauuy2
0987yuh|mnjkhuy6|nmbhgf|0987yuh
098iuhyj|4e5rtyguh|67tyughj|oijk
```

And code to import:

```
filename = 'dummy.txt';
nCols = 4;
delim = '|';
colFmt = repmat('%s',1,nCols);

fid = fopen(filename,'r');
header = textscan(fid, colFmt, 1, 'delimiter', delim); 
dataArray = textscan(fid, colFmt, 'delimiter', delim);
fclose(fid);

dataArray = [dataArray{:}]; % this "unpacks" the cell
```

Looks like this in workspace:
[image]

Comment: I think you should show how to use this approach on the OP's data (which mainly has different delimeters and data types), otherwise this is couldn't be considered an answer the question (since it solves a different problem).